# What is a formal parameter?

Tags: c++, c, language-agnostic, language-design

When compiling in C++ I often end up with error messages dealing with "formal parameters", such as

```
error C2719: 'b': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

I do understand the error, and the fact that `b` is a parameter of a function I am defining.

However, what does it mean that a parameter is *formal*? Can there be *informal* parameters as well?

I do notice that the term "formal parameter" appears in other languages as well, so I presume it is a more generic term not necessarily specific to C-family of languages? Are informal parameters supported by some subset of languages?

---

Upon seeing the answers, one final question: Where those names *formal parameter* and *actual parameter* origin from? Does it origin from the C standard, or is it an effect of calling it as such in some abstract language calculus?

Comment: In this particular case it means you're trying to pass more than three SSE parameters to a function and you're stuck with Visual Studio and the WIN32 ABI. ;-)

Comment: @Paul R: In this particular case I was passing an aligned parameter by value and not `const&`.

Comment: Regarding where the names come from: `formal` in mathematics is not the opposite of `informal`. `formal` comes from `form`, i.e. `formal` means well-defined. For example formal logic is not the opposite of informal logic, but a logic based on well-defined rules. Formal parameters therefore refer to the parameters that define the form of the function. Actual parameter is then obvious I think.

Comment: But then what is the opposite? "not well-defined"? I guess this shifts the discussion to the linguistic aspect so... never mind!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are *formal* and *actual* parameters:

```
void foo(int arg); //arg is a formal parameter

int main()
{
    int val = 1;
    foo(val);  //val is an actual parameter
}
```

From [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf):

**1.3.1 formal parameter (parameter)**

> an object or reference declared as part of a function declaration or
>   definition, or in the catch clause of an exception handler, that
>   acquires a value on entry to the function or handler; an identifier
>   from the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses immediately
>   following the macro name in a function-like macro definition; or a
>   template-parameter. Parameters are also known as formal arguments or
>   formal parameters.

**1.3.10 actual parameter (argument)**

> an expression in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses
>   in a function call expression, a sequence of preprocessing tokens in
>   the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function-like
>   macro invocation, the operand of throw, or an expression, type-id or
>   template-name in the comma-separated list bounded by the angle
>   brackets in a template instantiation. Also known as an actual argument
>   or actual parameter.

Comment: Is should be noted that these terms (formal and actual parameter) are deprecated by the C standard. The correct terms are "parameter" and "argument".

Comment: @R.. But they still function in other languages I believe? What's the source?

Comment: Source is the C standard, 3.3 and 3.15 in C99.

Comment: I meant, what is the source, the reason of this naming used in the standard. It seems the authors of the C standard did not invent this naming, but it was present before. They just explicitly (re-)defined it for C.

Answer (score 17):

Formal parameters are the parameters known at the function definition. The actual parameters are what you *actually* (hence the name) pass to the function when you call it.

```
void foo( int a ); // a is a formal parameter

foo(10); // 10 is the actual parameter
```

Comment: I thought the thing that you pass to a function is an "argument", while the thing that a function has is a "parameter"?

Answer (score 10):

It's a matter of being a little pedantic over terminology, but quite useful: The formal parameters are what you just think of function parameters:

```
int foo(bool a, float b);
```

Here `a` and `b` are formal parameters. The point is that in the function body, you're referring to those parameters "formally" without actually knowing their value. It is only when you actual *evaluate a function call expression* that the formal function parameters are *bound* to the function call arguments:

```
int result = foo(false, 1.5);
```

In this call expression, the value `false` of the first argument is bound to the formal parameter `a`, and similarly for the second argument.

The distinction between parameters and arguments is maybe more important to language designers and comiler writers, but as an example in C++, it can be very helpful to get your head around this when you're trying to follow the rules for template argument deduction.