# What do you call a method parameter in Java that takes values from a objects attribute?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

What do you call Java methods that take values from actual object or class attributes? If the very bottom method takes what is called a "Formal-Parameter", then what do you call one that takes actual attribute values like the `loopThruFiles()` does?

```
    int numOfFiles = 5;          
    shwEntries(entries, 0); 
} 

public static void loopThruFiles(int numOfFiles) {
    System.out.print("Interation: " + a + " : "); 
    for (int x = 0; x < files.length; x++) 
    System.out.print(entries[x] + " ");
    System.out.println( );
} 

public static void shwEntries(int[ ] entries, int a) {
    System.out.print("Interation: " + a + " : "); 
    for (int x = 0; x < entries.length; x++) 
    System.out.print(entries[x] + " ");
    System.out.println( );
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand what it is you're asking. Both methods take parameters. The loopThru... method simply *ignores* its parameter, and have no clue as to why, since this makes the parameter unhelpful, confusing and totally unnecessary.

Comment: A parameter is a parameter. It doesn't matter where an argument for that parameter comes from.

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing "parameter" with "argument", or asking for the definitions of both, but this is only a guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a formal parameter, in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494316/what-is-a-formal-parameter-in-java)

Comment: Its the books that I'm reading, they're referencing arguments, as if are the same as actual parameters. I just want clarity on what I should call them.

Comment: You would call the token in the method declaration the parameter. When you call the method, you pass in an argument, but in my experience, most programmers are not that "formal" with these terms. The method itself does not have any different "name" based on what is passed in.

Comment: In a method declaration like `void shwEntries(int[ ] entries, int a)` the `entries` and `a` are named "formal parameters". We know that at runtime a caller will pass values for these but we don't know what these values will be. When calling the method like `shwEntries(entries, 0);` actual values will be passed to the method.

Comment: The values that are "provided" by the instance or class are called "fields" and even when we access them in a method they are still called "fields".